# Bulk error handling in Access VBA. How to create an error handling method to handle all errors in a class

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

I am try to make my VBA program not so fussy by adding some robust error handling. I know that typical error handling in VBA goes something like this:

```
Sub doSomething()
On Error GoTo errorHandler

Regular code here 

Exit sub 

errorHandler:
Lots of code to do something about it

End Sub
```

The problem is that my program has what feels like a million methods and to add the errorHandler: code to every single method (when MANY of the errors will be the same for several methods) feels like a waste of time and keystrokes. Is there any way to make a error handling method instead of having lots of code in each method under the errorHandler:?

In my code naive mind it seems like I could do something like this:

```
Sub doSomething()
On Error GoTo errorHandler

Regular code here 
Exit sub 

errorHandler:
Call the method that really handles the errors
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub doSomething()
On Error GoTo method that handles all errors 
Regular code here 
End Sub
```

I am pretty new to VBA and definitely new to correctly handling errors in VBA. Any help or direction would be fabulous. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a great link for different ways to use [error handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) in VBA

Comment: After playing with syntax it looks like my first idea will work. Although I would still love any input about whether or not that is a good idea/best practice. Thanks!

Comment: Years ago I got 'volunteered' for a large Access project that had no error traps -- I am doing better now with the pills and counseling. I created some code that would insert a standard trap in every form/module/report that the user selected and would also capture the error details (number, desc, form, sub, etc.) to a central table for analysis. Code also could insert line numbers in the VBA so the message would tell exact line of the error. If interested, I could share the code. Yes, in my opinion, error traps are highly desirable.

Comment: The first method you suggest should work fine, but if you want to trap error message etc, you'll have to do so before going to the next sub.